# Testing MySQL compression on my live database

Tags: mysql, database, compression, innodb

I have giant tables with lots of `VARCHAR`, `TINYTEXT`, and `TEXT` fields. As I'm not an expert in MySQL DB I've recently came across the compression feature of MySQL database by seeing this page [InnoDB Table Compression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-compression.html).

I've searched and read multiple pages and came across that I need to set the following parameters and apply these changes to my `my.cnf`:

```
innodb_file_per_table=1; (this is already set)
innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
```

and for table structure:

```
 ...
 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED
 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8; (possibly I need to do a trial-and-error to find a
                    better key_block_size that fits better to my case)
```

So, I want to initially test and see how this compression would benefit me on table sizes and hopefully manage my space better. To do this test I'll generate a sample table with few hundreds or thousands rows of the original table and do the trials and performance measuring.

Since this would be a testing process and since I don't have any other server to do the test on, I don't want to risk anything.

**Here is my question:**

If I change my `my.cnf` file (by adding `innodb_file_format=Barracuda;`) on my current server and restart the server would it have any effect on my existing tables/data that have `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`?

I couldn't find any place answering/mentioning this, so thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`innodb_file_format` applies to newly created tables, not existing tables.  I don't think you even need to do a restart.

The `SET GLOBAL` commands need root permission, but after that, you can run as a regular user.

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;
SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=1;      -- already done
SET GLOBAL innodb_large_prefix=1;        -- optional
logout & login (to get the global values);
ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;   -- This assumes table exists
CREATE TABLE tbl ( ...
    )  ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;            -- This assumes creating
```

Comment: So, by this you mean there would be no harm and/or effect on my current tables and data if I only set `innodb_file_format=Barracuda;` in `my.cnf` (or do `SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;`)? If yes, I'd be good to start my tests :)

Comment: I believe that is true.  But I am never offended if you do further research, test it in a separate system, etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks, it worked as expected. After setting `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` in my `my.cnf` I now have all four file formats available in PMA. This means there won't be any effect on my existing tables with `ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT`